# multirow out of boundary

Tags: multirow

Try to create a table with a merged cell. For some reason, there are two empty rows and the number are out of boudary? How should I make the merged cell start from the top instead of with two empty rows?

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
            & \textbf{Unqiue}  & \textbf{Common}   \\ \hline
C0   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} 
                    \\
                    1  \\      
                    2 \\      
                    3 \\ 
                    \\
            \end{tabular} 
            & \multirow{2}{*}{
                \begin{tabular}{c}
                    1 \\
                    2 \\
                    3 \\
                    4 \\
                    5 \\
                    6 \\
                    7 \\
                    8 \\
                    9 
                \end{tabular}
            } \\
            \cline{2-2}
C1   &   \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} 
                     \\
                    1 \\ 
                    2 \\ 
                    \\
                \end{tabular}   
            &
                                        \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: output table]

Comment: unrelated but `\begin{table}[]` means the table is not allowed anywhere, it generates a warning and the `[]` option is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In defining it you should consider how many text lines in adjacent columns it span. In your case is nine such lines (from which four are empty). Unfortunately, this is not sufficient to achieve what you after, you also need to move it contents up for distance for about `5ex`:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
            & \textbf{Unqiue}  & \textbf{Common}   \\ \hline
C0   & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
                    \\
                    1  \\
                    2 \\
                    3 \\
                    \\
            \end{tabular}
            & \multirow{9}{*}[5ex]{  % <---
                \begin{tabular}{c}
                    1 \\
                    2 \\
                    3 \\
                    4 \\
                    5 \\
                    6 \\
                    7 \\
                    8 \\
                    9
                \end{tabular}
            } \\
            \cline{2-2}
C1   &   \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
                     \\
                    1 \\
                    2 \\
                    \\
                \end{tabular}
            &
                                        \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

However, with use of the `tabularray` package you can write simpler code which will get nicer result. Using it you not need to bother, haw many lines are in rows spanned by multi row cell:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\begin{tblr}{hlines,
             colspec = {*{3}{Q[c, m]}},
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries},
             vspan=even
             }
             
    &   Unqiue  &   Common  \\
%
C0   & {    1  \\
            2 \\
            3}  &   \SetCell[r=2]{} {   1 \\
                                        2 \\
                                        3 \\
                                        4 \\
                                        5 \\
                                        6 \\
                                        7 \\
                                        8 \\
                                        9}      \\
C1   &  {   1 \\
            2 \\
            }   &                               \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Syntax of the `tabularray` table differ a bit from syntax used in the "classic" tables. For it please consult package documentation.